# How to get predictions/autocompletion of URLs in a simple android browser?

Tags: android, url, browser, webview

I've created a simple android browser. I have used **EditText** for URL and **Webview** for loading webpages. Although the browser works fine when I put the complete URL path, I need a functionality by which I can get predictions/auto-completion of partially put URLs. Please let me know if following options are valid -

- Using AutoCompleteTextView instead of EditText with a database of all the available websites on the internet(More than 1 billion websites!! Where can I get such dynamically updating database??)
- Saving URLs which are frequently being used by the user and use them as a prediction in an AutoCompleteTextView.(How can I add these URLs in a dynamic AutoCompleteTextView/Database??)

Currently I am using google search as a workaround. Please provide your views on how this can be achieved.